# I am seeing OnAfterRenderAsync() get called before OnInitializedAsync() completes

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Is this possible? That OnAfterRenderAsync() will be called before OnInitializedAsync() completes?

If so, I then need to have my code in OnAfterRenderAsync(), in this case, be called at the end of OnInitializedAsync() instead. It's a piece of cake to have a method that is called from each and whoever is 2nd executes it.

In this case is a counter inside a `lock { ... }` the best approach? Or should I take another approach?

In _Host.cshtml I have:

```
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="Server" />
```

In this mode OnInitializedAsync() is called once.

Comment: Well, in the  server flavor, by default it deliberately runs Init 2x: once to fill in your basic layout, and another to fill in the content.  One option would be to disable this feature.  I've always disliked this behavior, tbh.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I just updated the question. I have it set to `render-mode="Server"` so OnInitializedAsync() is only called once. thanks

Comment: I think with .net 8 there should be a lot more flexibility with how your page behaves during initial loading.  If this is something that you're already working on, might be worth upgrading right now?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I'm on .NET 8 but this might be a .NET issues. [So I've asked there](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/discussions/51976). Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes. It is well [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-7.0#lifecycle-events):

> *Note*
> *Asynchronous actions performed in lifecycle events might not have completed before a component is rendered.*

> at the end of OnInitializedAsync() instead.

Why not call it there, and only there, all the time.

> is a counter inside a `lock { ... }` the best approach?

No, I would stay away from `lock`. The lifecycle is effectively single-threaded so you don't need it. Using a counter or boolean is thread-safe already.

Comment: I have two cases. The first is needing JavaScript to get some properties from the browser (timezone, location). The second is accessing a `ref=` to a control on the page. If not `lock{ ... }`, what approach would you take to know if the other has completed and so ok to now call my code? TIA

Comment: All this code is async but not multi-threaded. So test for null or false somewhere without `lock`

Comment: I thought that Blazor has a thread pool that it uses for the various tasks? And that we're not guaranteed that a task will be in the UI thread? Did I misunderstand that? Assuming it is a concern [I came up with this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77462353/how-to-execute-code-when-the-second-method-completes) I think it's clean & fast.

Comment: All UI code runs on the `Synchronization Context` thread unless you switch it.  You may await code that is running on another thread [such as timer or data call] and need to handle the context in which callbacks are run, but  I believe the awaiter is on the UI thread.

Comment: The whole lifecycle runs on a sync context, and that only allows one Thread at a time. So you can think of it as a single (UI) thread. The thread-pool is not used when you do some async I/O.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis & HH - thank you for the clarification on the `Synchronization Context`. Although, when `OnInitializedAsync()` returns a Task then won't `OnAfterRenderAsync()` be called in that same thread? For example in initialized I read from the DB which returns a task, that returns on up so afterRender is called while initialized is waiting on the DB task?

Comment: Yes, but it's all a a timing issue.  If you use my `DocumentedComponentBase` and use `Task.Delay(x)`, you will find that when x = 1 you get a different sequence to when x=100.  As I've stated elsewhere, the SC prioritizes loaded code over UI event code.  If you get an hiatus, the UI code gets run, no hiatus and the UI code gets bumped down.  It's why `Task.Yield` and `Task.Delay` may give different results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some demo code that documents it does happen and how to detect the `OnInitializedAsync` completion.

I've added several renders during `OnInitializedAsync` to show that it's only the last `OnAfterRender` that runs after `OnInitializedAsync`.  The code uses a special version of `ComponentBase` that douments each step of the process with Console writes.  It's available in the `Blazr.BaseComponents` package.

Why?  As I've already said in previous answers, `OnAfterRender` is a UI event not directly coupled with the lifecycle methods.  The Synchronisation Context prioritizes posted code (by the Renderer) over UI interaction code (UI events).  When UI events run is dictated by what's on the SC queue [such as how long real awaits task].

Here's the demo code which shows how to detect the last render using a simple bool:

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits Blazr.BaseComponents.ComponentBase.DocumentedComponentBase

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

@code {
    private bool _onInitialized;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(250);
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(250);
        this.StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(250);

        // OnInitialized and and OnInitializedAsync have both now completed
        _onInitialized = true;
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (_onInitialized)
        {
            // runs only once on the last render after OnInitializedSync completes
            _onInitialized = false;
            Console.WriteLine("After Initialized code has run.");
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the console output to show what's happening:

```
f1b4 - Home => Component Initialized
f1b4 - Home => Component Attached
f1b4 - Home => SetParametersAsync Started
f1b4 - Home => OnInitialized sequence Started
f1b4 - Home => Awaiting Task completion
f1b4 - Home => StateHasChanged Called
f1b4 - Home => Render Queued
f1b4 - Home => Component Rendered
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
f1b4 - Home => StateHasChanged Called
f1b4 - Home => Render Queued
f1b4 - Home => Component Rendered
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
f1b4 - Home => StateHasChanged Called
f1b4 - Home => Render Queued
f1b4 - Home => Component Rendered
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
f1b4 - Home => OnInitialized sequence Completed
f1b4 - Home => OnParametersSet Sequence Started
f1b4 - Home => StateHasChanged Called
f1b4 - Home => Render Queued
f1b4 - Home => Component Rendered
f1b4 - Home => OnParametersSet Sequence Completed
f1b4 - Home => SetParametersAsync Completed
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Started
After Initialized code has run.
f1b4 - Home => OnAfterRenderAsync Completed
```

Comment: This code assumes that there will be an OnAfterRenderAsync() call after OnInitializedAsync() completes - correct? Is that guaranteed? Because if so, this is a clean way to call after both are complete.

Comment: Yes and No, but your assumption is correct, and yes it is a clean (and simple which I like) way to solve the issue.  At the end of the `SetParametersAsync` i.e. at the end  of `SetParametersAsync` there will be a call to ``StateHasChanged` -  which will lead to the `OnAfterRenderAsync()` UI event.  Use my `DocumentedComponentBase` to prove the case in your code.